# What does err and doc mean in cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){})?

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

This is from [official MongoDB documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#toarray).

toArray
`cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){})` converts the cursor object into an array of all the matching records. Probably the most convenient way to retrieve results but be careful with large datasets as every record is loaded into memory.

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs){
    console.log("retrieved records:");
    console.log(docs);
});
```

What does err and doc mean in cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){})?

Comment: err - error if happened during reading from cursor. If no error then null. Docs - array of documents read from cursor.

Comment: Better documentation for `toArray` can be found here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docs` is an array with all the documents returned by the cursor.

When there was an error, `err` is an object which describes that error.

Comment: Could you link official documentation that substantiates this?